# Pylance not showing suggestions in certain condition

Tags: pylance

Environment data
Language Server version v2023.6.10
OS and version: windows10
Python version: Python 3.9.13 via Anaconda.

Expected behavior
it is expected to have suggestion after '.' ,but it has nothing and the highlight doesn't show either
[no highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgyyL.png)
[no suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aKsq.png)

i have searched many methods, but none works

Actual behavior
in pycharm it works well, it should have highlight and suggestion

Comment: Do you have the right python interpreter selected? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters if you're sure you have, you could try running `>Python: Clear Cache and Reload Window`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.